# Subspaces, condition on dimensions, orthogonal complement

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality

Let $U$ be a finite dimensional vector space, endowed with an inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$, and let $V,W$ be some non-trivial subspaces of $U$. We know that $\dim W < \dim V$. Does it entail there exists $u\in (V\cap W^\perp)\setminus \{0\}$?

Comment: You mention $V$ only once. Are you sure about that?

Comment: Thanks @JoséCarlosSantos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true. Suppose for a contradiction that $V\cap W^\perp = \left\{0\right\}$. Then using the formula for the dimension of a subspace sum we have
\begin{align*}
\dim(V + W^\perp) &= \dim V + \dim W^\perp - \dim (V\cap W^\perp)\\
& = \dim V + \dim W^\perp\\
&> \dim V + \dim V^\perp\\
&= \dim U
\end{align*}
where we used in the third line that $\dim W < \dim V \iff \dim W^\perp > \dim V^\perp$. The result is impossible since $V+W^\perp$ is a subspace of $U$.